# Can i make some annotation required in classes that implements my interface?

Tags: java

I have this interface:

```
public interface IDbTable extends Serializable
{
    public int getId();
}
```

I need to obligate all the classes that implements IDbTable, to have an annotation "@DatabaseTable" and at least one field inside class that have "@DatabaseField".
The only way of implementing IDbTable needs to be like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Something")
public static class TestTable implements IDbTable
{
            @DatabaseField
            public int id;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Is this possible with interface or inheritance?
Today i have an unit test that scan all the classes and check this requirements. Is this a good practice?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the unit test approach is the best that comes to mind.

Comment: There is no way to make this requirements generate an error? Without having to run the unit tests? The unit test thing seems a big workaround to me

Comment: It is possible to check it in runtime, is it suitable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply annotations to an interface that will be inherited by the implementing class, according to Java documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an
>   Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type
>   declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class
>   declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this
>   type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for
>   the annotation type. This process will be repeated until an annotation
>   for this type is found, or the top of the class hierarchy (Object) is
>   reached. If no superclass has an annotation for this type, then the
>   query will indicate that the class in question has no such annotation.
>
> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that
>   this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
>   superclasses; **annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.**

Comment: But see http://fusionsoft-online.com/press-releases-java-annotations.php for a library that says it allows annotation inheritance for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use annotation processing, to check that the requiered annotation is present in your class when it is sent to your framework, or at build/deployment time.